# Bootstrap Expandable Sidebar Element

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I have a sidebar that looks somewhat like this site's sidebar: http://scotch.io/

If you hover over tutorials it expands the element with a menu of items to choose from.

What I am trying to do is get it so if I click one of those elements it shows a nice popover instead of expanding the entire sidebar. Something that could ease in, but if it just shows up that's fine too.

I looked at the bootstrap 3 popover but it seems to only work with buttons, and what I am using is this for one of my list elements:

```
<li class="sidebar-available-rooms" data-container="body">
    <a class="fa fa-comments" id="sidebar-icon-comments" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right"></a>
    <span class="sidebar-text" id="sidebar-available-rooms-text">Available Rooms</span>
</li>
```

I would to be able to click it and in the simplest form, get a popover to the right of the element.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use a little piece of jQuery and it also works on links.

```
$("[data-toggle=popover]").popover({html:true})
```

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HsZ9q/5/